# Word macro to auto-update formula field without Ctrl+A, F9

Tags: microsoft-word, automation, field-codes

I want a formula field to update automatically when its source field (another row in the same table) is updated, without having to update/recalculate the field value by pressing F9.

Is this possible?  If so, what should I research to make the calculated fields **auto-update** on the edit of a source field so the end user doesn't have to press **Ctrl+A, F9** each time they edit a value?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible.  In Word, formulas (fields, really) are updated when you open the document or when you explicitly ask for an update (as in the F9 case).

[Microsoft reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-in-a-Word-or-Outlook-table-cbd0596e-ea8a-485e-a35d-b2cb2c4f3e27#__update_formula_results)

Comment: Bummer. Do you know if there's a way to get around this limitation, e.g. embedding an Excel sheet in a Word document to take advantage of Excel's formula and auto-update functionality?  (Separate question, but related)

Comment: Depends on the embedding.  If you insert the Excel object into the document you can treat it as a linked object or an embedded one.  If it's linked, then updates to the source spreadsheet will update the view in Word too.  However, this seems even more work than Ctrl A-F9.